# Spring web application displays blank page for the first request

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working in a spring web application and faces a strange behavior.

when hitting the application URL, the browser displays blank page and I should reload the page to work properly.

The application runs behind nginx and there are a chunk of redirection rules.

I can not find more specific words to describe this issue.

Where to start debugging ?

my server.xml

`

```
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
```

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
       connectionTimeout="20000" maxThreads="600"  minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" 
           useBodyEncodingForURI="true" enableLookups="false"
           redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
    scheme="https" secure="true"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
URIEncoding="UTF-8" 
keystoreFile="my key store"
keystorePass="my password"
/>
<Connector port="8013" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"  
connectionTimeout="20000" maxThreads="600"  minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" 
           useBodyEncodingForURI="true" enableLookups="false"
 />

<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
         resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

  </Host>
</Engine>
```

`

Comment: Spring is Java. nginx is a Webserver. What is your Application-Server? Tomcat? JBoss? Glassfish?

Comment: tomcat application server

Comment: Please post the server.xml.

Comment: Tomcat isn't an application server, it is a mere servlet engine which makes a big difference.

Comment: Thnx Michael for the note

Comment: @PeterRader server.xml is posted

Comment: @PeterRader this post describes the same scenario http://www.coderanch.com/t/465816/Tomcat/Tomcat-serving-Blank-Page-shows but the solution provided at the end does not work with me. I changed the wait_timeout and interactive_timeout and the situation is the same

Comment: Can you Browse the URL using port 8080?

Comment: ok, how do you connect tomcat an nginx? Via AJP or Proxy or Redirection? Its the best you post the nginx-config too.

Comment: nginx connected to tomcat using proxy

Comment: So its not a Bug: nginx is missconfigured! The best is to ask a Admin, tag this question with nginx and add the nginx-config.